# Flutter DevOps CI/CD

Tags: flutter, deployment, devops, continuous-deployment, cicd

How to build a CD in my Flutter app on a Windows machine?

I want to build DevOps concepts in my Flutter app but I'm using a Windows machine so Fast Lane does not support it. Are any other options available to make the continuous delivery in Windows machines?

Comment: you can look into codemagic CI/CD for flutter or github actions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the git repository that you are using:

- GitHub: Use GitHub Actions
- GitLab: Use GitLab CI/CD
- Microsoft Azure: Configure Azure DevOps pipeline

I use a tool called [Odevio](https://odevio.com/), and there is a documentation with an example for each one of the pipeline mentioned above here: https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CICD. You can have a look and get inspired to create your own pipeline.